# How to set focus to input after the element stops moving?

Tags: reactjs, focus

In React a have a search bar which shows up after I click "Open" button. Search bar appears smoothly because I use translateX property. Then I would like to use focus() on the input element in this search bar. I tried to use refs. Focus appears but it appears as soon as I press the button and stays all the way the search bar moves from one part of the screen to the other(rememeber, it because I use translateX). So it all rides before my eyes. How to make focus appers after the search bar 'reached the destination' on the screen? I tried

```
  if (props.visibleSearchBar) {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(inputRef.current).focus()
  }
```

instead of

```
 if (props.visibleSearchBar) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
  } // same story


 const Search = (props) => {
     let inputRef = useRef(null);       
     if (props.visibleSearchBar) {
          inputRef.current.focus();
       }

     return (
       <div>
        <input ref={inputRef} />   
       </div >
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the input initially, and enable it after the transition ends.

something like this, (it is not tested).

```
const [disabled, setDisabledState] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
const callback = () => {
 setDisableState(false)
 inputRef.current.focus();
}
inputRef.current.addEventListener('transitionend', callback)

return () => inputRef.current.removeEventListener('transitioned', callback)
}, [])


 return (
       <div>
        <input ref={inputRef}  disabled={disabled}/>   
       </div >
     )
```

Comment: Very well! It worked! By the way you forgot to add 'n' in the word 'transitionend'. I also added another boolean state to stop this transitionn from happening endelessly. Thank you very much!